# Getting posts by users I am following

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

So, a user can follow multiple people, who can create multiple posts, I am morphing my posts, because multiple items can create posts,

So, my Timeline relationship to the user is like so:

```
/**
 * Get the owner.
 *
 * @return 
 *  App\Modules\Account\Entites\User
 *  App\Modules\Groups\Entites\Groups
 *  App\Modules\Pages\Entites\Pages
 *  App\Modules\Events\Entites\Events
 */
public function owner()
{
    return $this->morphTo('owner');;
}
```

**Timeline table:**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('timeline', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('location')->nullable();
        $table->string('feeling')->nullable();
        $table->string('type')->nullable();
        $table->string('privacy')->default('public');
        $table->integer('owner_id');
        $table->string('owner_type');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Now, my user can follow other users, and pages, so that, too is being morphed like so:

```
/**
 * Return item followings.
 *
 * @param string $class
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function followings($class = __CLASS__)
{
    return $this->morphedByMany($class, config('follow.morph_prefix'), config('follow.followable_table'))
                ->wherePivot('relation', '=', Follow::RELATION_FOLLOW)
                ->withPivot('followable_type', 'relation', 'created_at');
}


/**
 * Return followers.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(config('follow.user_model'), config('follow.morph_prefix'), config('follow.followable_table'))
                ->wherePivot('relation', '=', Follow::RELATION_FOLLOW)
                ->withPivot('followable_type', 'relation', 'created_at');
}
```

Following structure:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create(config('follow.followable_table', 'followables'), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('followable_id');
        $table->string('followable_type')->index();
        $table->string('relation')->default('follow')->comment('folllow/like/subscribe/favorite/');
        $table->timestamp('created_at');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references(config('follow.users_table_primary_key', 'id'))
            ->on(config('follow.users_table_name', 'users'))
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Now, I am trying to get the statuses(posts) by people I am following:

Example data;

```
INSERT INTO `social`.`timeline` 
    (
        `id`, 
        `status`, 
        `location`, 
        `feeling`, 
        `type`, 
        `privacy`, 
        `owner_id`, 
        `owner_type`, 
        `created_at`, 
        `updated_at`, 
        `deleted_at`
    ) 
VALUES     
    (
        '2', 
        'hellov', 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        'public', 
        '1', 
        'App\\Modules\\Account\\Entities\\User', 
        '2018-02-05 20:02:08', 
        '2018-02-05 20:02:08', 
        NULL
    );
```

The owner type can be multiple (check the owner method at the very top) my query

```
    $statuses = $this
        ->timeline
        ->whereHas('owner.followers', function ($q) use ($user) {
            return $q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
        })
        // ->whereHas('owner.likes', function ($q) use ($user) {
        //     return $q->where('id', Auth::user()->id);
        // })
        ->orderBy('timeline.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

But this throws an error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::followers()

So, my question is, how come I am getting the error when that relationship exists, and how can I fix it?

I have built a query so you can understand my logic a bit better

```
/**
 * Scope a query to friends and followers statuses.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeFriendsAndFollowers($query)
{
    $query->leftJoin('followables', function ($join) {
        $join
            ->on('timeline.owner_id', '=', 'followables.followable_id')
            ->on('timeline.owner_type', '=', 'followables.followable_type');
    })
    ->leftJoin('friendships', function ($join) {
        $join
            ->on('timeline.owner_id', '=', 'friendships.recipient_id');
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query
            ->where('followables.user_id', Auth::user()->id, 'and')
            ->where('privacy', 'public')
            ->orWhere('privacy', 'private');
    })
    ->Orwhere(function($query) {
        $query
            ->where(function($query) {
                $query
                    ->where('friendships.sender_id', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->orWhere('friendships.recipient_id', Auth::user()->id);
            })   
            ->where('privacy', 'public')
            ->orWhere('privacy', 'private');
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('timeline.owner_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('timeline.owner_type', get_class(Auth::user()));
    });                                 
}
```

Comment: No, `$this->timeline` is just assigned to my timeline model.. Imagine it as `Timeline::`